# Importing .geotiffs and wavelet denoise plug-in - GIMP

Tags: geotiff-tiff, smoothing, breaklines, gimp

I am trying to run the wavelet denoise plug-in tool on GIMP to smooth a .geotiff. Unfortunately when I import the .tiff, the spatial refernece is lost and the image appears black. My goal was to smooth away uncorrelated roughness while preserving breaklines. Does anyone have any experience with this plugin or importing .tiff's in GIMP.